# Determine if the matrix is linearly independent (complex numbers) 4x4

Tags: matrices

I am trying to determine if this is linearly independent and I continue to get the wrong answer. I have gotten the determinant to be both $4$ and $2$ although the answer says it should be

$2-2i$ and therefore since it does not equal zero it would be linearly independent. I am not sure where the answer $2-2i$ comes from.

$$\begin{array}{l}1&0&0&1\\0&1&-i&0\\0&1&i&0\\i&0&0&-i\end{array}$$

does anyone know how to do this using coffactors???

Comment: You can compute the determinant by reducing the matrix to triangular form, as you would for a real matrix.  Is that what you tried to do?

Comment: No I have mostly been taught to do it by cofactor but I am struggling to understand it. Would i need to do the co factor method for each row and column or just one? the instructor is very confusing

Comment: Checking online, I do see that the determinant is 4... hmm

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-determinant-calculator/%5Cdet%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D1%260%260%261%5C%5C%200%261%26-i%260%5C%5C%200%261%26i%260%5C%5C%20i%260%260%26-i%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D

Comment: I get $4$.  You only expand by minors along one row or column.

Comment: Yeah... thats why i am so lost, because the text book says its 2-2i and therefore linearly independent

Comment: It is possible that the textbook has made a mistake, and it seems like this is the case here. Regardless, your answer is correct, and I would accept it.

Comment: you determine linear independence with the determinant right?

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Either the answer in the book is wrong, or you have miscopied the matrix.  And yes, as long as the determinant is not zero, the rows and the columns are both linearly independent.